# How to separate array of objects with specific array prefix in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings

I planed to prepare this array by separate those kind of array with index specification

**Default data format**

```
[{
      "Emp_code": "EM-00001",
      "Emp_title": "11",
      "Emp_firstName": "22",
      "Emp_lastName": "33",
      "Emp_dateOfBirth": "20-10-1985",
      "Con_title": "title",
      "Con_email": "email",
      "Con_addres": "address",
      "Con_phone": "phone"
    }]
```

**Wanted format**

```
[{
  "emp": {
      "code": "EM-00001",
      "title": "11",
      "firstName": "22",
      "lastName": "33",
      "dateOfBirth": "20-10-1985",
  },
  "con": {
      "Con_title": "title",
      "Con_email": "email",
      "Con_addres": "address",
      "Con_phone": "phone"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Ok and what have you tried? It's not a super complicated requirement, you can loop through the properties, building a new object along the way. Check if the key prefix exists as a key on the object you're building and if not add it, then add the key/value pair as a sub-property (minus the key prefix). At the moment you're just stating your requirements, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You mean there can be any number of formats such as "emp" , "con" ,..  but only seperate these by key -> "con" by "Con_title" "emp" by "Emp_code"?

Comment: I'm going to separate based on array object prefix, current we have only two but it could flexible if it contain more prefixes. anyway I have tried many time with above mention or login but I just starter with typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var item = {
  "Emp_code": "EM-00001",
  "Emp_title": "11",
  "Emp_firstName": "22",
  "Emp_lastName": "33",
  "Emp_dateOfBirth": "20-10-1985",
  "Con_title": "title",
  "Con_email": "email",
  "Con_addres": "address",
  "Con_phone": "phone"
}
var data = [item, item];

var res = []

for (var item of data) {
  var temp = {};
  res.push(temp);
  for (var prop in item) {
    var parts = prop.split('_');
    var prefix = parts[0].toLowerCase();
    temp[prefix] = temp[prefix] || {};
    temp[prefix][prefix === 'emp' ? parts[1] : prop] = item[prop]
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the property names to a starting accumulator of [{ emp: {} }, { con: {} }] and each iteration you can add the property to the corresponding item in the accumulator.

```js
const data = [{
      "Emp_code": "EM-00001",
      "Emp_title": "11",
      "Emp_firstName": "22",
      "Emp_lastName": "33",
      "Emp_dateOfBirth": "20-10-1985",
      "Con_title": "title",
      "Con_email": "email",
      "Con_addres": "address",
      "Con_phone": "phone"
    }];
    
const format = obj =>
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj[0]).reduce(
    (acc, prop) => {
      if (prop.startsWith('Emp_')) {
        acc[0].emp[prop.replace('Emp_', '')] = obj[0][prop];
      } else {
        acc[1].con[prop] = obj[0][prop];
      }
      return acc;
    },
    [{ emp: {} }, { con: {} }]
  );
 
 console.log(format(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script checks element using loops, then splits them into prefix & suffix. Then checks for whether prefix is present in resulting array or not. If it's not then adds that prefix into array & prepares the result.

```
var a = [{"Emp_code": "EM-00001", "Emp_title": "11", "Emp_firstName": "22", "Emp_lastName": "33", "Emp_dateOfBirth": "20-10-1985", "Con_title": "title", "Con_email": "email", "Con_addres": "address", "Con_phone": "phone"}];
var b = [];
$.each(a, function(arrKey, arrData){
    var tempArr = {};
    $.each(arrData, function(key, value){
        var arrKey = key.split('_');
        var prefix = arrKey[0];
        var suffix = arrKey[1];
        if( $.inArray(prefix, Object.keys(tempArr)) == -1 ) {
            tempArr[prefix] = {};
        }
        tempArr[prefix][suffix]=value;
    });
    b.push(tempArr);
});
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Any text to explain what is happening?

Comment: Edited an answer.